# Issue when using PKCS7Padding when decrypting. Use IvParameterSpec or AlgorithmParameters to provide it

Tags: android, encryption, keystore, android-keystore

How do I decrypt the string which already encrypted in the below sample, when I use below code I get exception

```
String transforation = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding";

KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
keyStore.load(null);
SecretKey secretKey = (SecretKey) keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME, null);

// encrypt
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(transforation);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
String encriptedPassword = cipher.doFinal("Some Password".getBytes("UTF-8"));

// decrypt
cipher = Cipher.getInstance(transforation);
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
String password = new String(cipher.doFinal(encriptedPassword), "UTF-8"));
```

if I am providing **encryptCipher.getIV()** I am able to decrypt

```
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(encryptCipher.getIV()));
```

but the problem is encryptCipher.getIV() is returning random key every time when I run the app.

Answer (score 3):

The Cipher's `init` method's java doc says

> If this cipher requires any algorithm parameters and params is null, the underlying cipher implementation is supposed to generate the required parameters itself (using provider-specific default or random values) if it is being initialized for encryption or key wrapping, and raise an InvalidAlgorithmParameterException if it is being initialized for decryption or key unwrapping. The generated parameters can be retrieved using getParameters or getIV (if the parameter is an IV).

So when you don't pass in the `Algorithm parameters` (3rd argument in the `init` method), it will generate a random parameters each time. So when you do the `encryptionCipher.getIV()`, it will return different each time.

If you need to use IV (advisable to use):

- you can use a fixed value to initialize your cipher (not highly secure)
- Or you can generate random IV each time (more secure) and store it along with your encrypted value, and parse it out when decrypting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to record the **IV** used on the encryption, and provide it along with the encrypted data, so it's availabe when decrypting.

A simple way to do this, is to preprend the encryped data with the **IV**, and then obtain/remove it prior to decrypting. The IV don't need to be secret, but it should be different for each encrypt.